# What does Ercc1-/- / DAT-Cre+ mean?

Tags: genetics, gene

I really need to know what *Ercc1-/- / DAT-Cre+*  mean. I think the 1st part means that the mice don't have the Ercc1 gene (knockout). But what about *DAT-Cre+*?

This question arised from reading the following paper: "[Inefficient DNA Repair Is an Aging-Related Modifier of Parkinson’s Disease" (Sara Sepe et al)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27210754).

*Ercc1-/- / DAT-Cre+* mice are mentioned several times, For e.g.:

> Ercc1−/−DAT-Cre+ mice are viable and normal at birth. At 26 weeks of
>   age, specific deletion of Ercc1 in DA neurons mice elicits reduction
>   in tyrosine hydroxylase (TH) immunoreactivity in the SNpc and in the
>   striatum (Figures 1A and 1B). Aging profoundly exacerbates SNpc DA
>   neurons reduction, as evidenced in 52-week-old Ercc1−/−DAT-Cre+ mice
>   (Figure 1C). Damage is limited in DA neurons and other populations
>   remain unaffected, as indicated by unchanged NeuN immunoreactivity
>   (Figures 1A and 1B). Overall, these findings demonstrate that Ercc1
>   function and NER are essential to preserve integrity of the DA
>   circuits in time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but you should add the link to the paper. Moreover, copy pasting the text is better than pasting an image, for better searchability and rendering. I have done the both for you this time.

Comment: I have answered your question but the answer was pretty obvious. They mention it in the paragraph just before your excerpt. You should have read the paper more carefully. Questions like this ("homeworks") without adequate effort from the asker are generally not appreciated and put on hold.  "*Homework*" is interpreted to mean any academic or other assignment, test preparation, or task given in relation to a class, educational setting, or self-learning.

Answer (score 2):

Ercc1-/-DAT-Cre means the mice with Cre recombinase mediated conditional knockout of Ercc1 in the DA neurons. DAT-Cre is the mouse strain that expresses Cre recombinase from the promoter of Dopamine transporter.

> **Cre-recombinase:loxP (Cre-loxP) system was used to generate mutants
>   with targeted deletion in dopamine transporter (DAT)-expressing
>   neurons.** Specificity of Cre recombinase activity was validated using a
>   lacZ reporter that confirmed expression in DA neurons of the SNpc and
>   not in other cell types, such as serotonergic neurons of the Raphe
>   nucleus (Figure S1).

From supplementary information:

> Conditional mutants were generated using the Cre-recombinase:loxP
>   (Cre-loxP) system and crossing a strain carrying an Ercc1 allele
>   flanked by loxP sites (Ercc1fl/fl), with a strain expressing the Cre
>   recombinase under the control of the specific Dopamine Transporter
>   (DAT) promoter (Zhuang et al., 2005). We validated the specificity of
>   Cre recombinase activity by generating DAT-Cre+ROSA26-lacZ reporter
>   (Soriano, 1999), which confirmed expression in DA neurons of the SNpc
>   and not in other cell types, such as serotonergic neurons of the Raphe
>   nucleus (Supp. fig. 1)